# Markdown equivalent of `org-indent-mode`?

Tags: indentation, tabs, markdown-mode

What's the simplest way of ensuring that the text below a headline in a Markdown file is aligned with the headline? In `org-mode` you can accomplish this by calling `org-indent-mode`. Is there a similar function for Markdown?

At the moment, using `markdown-mode`, I get something like this:

```
# Heading 1
This is some text below the first heading.

## Heading 2
This is some text below the second heading.
```

I'd like instead to have something like this:

```
# Heading 1
  This is some text below the first heading.

## Heading 2.
   This is some text below the second heading.
```

Incidentally, and this may be related to [this issue](https://github.com/jrblevin/markdown-mode/issues/388), if I just try to indent the text below a heading using `TAB`, I get a four space indentation, even though I have `(setq-default tab-width 2)` in my `init` file.